# how to add some text just below chapter title in tex

Tags: sectioning

I am writing a tex document using book document class. I am using below code to remove 'chapter' from heading

`\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\Huge\bfseries} {} {0pt} {\thechapter.\ }`

Now, the chapter using say `\chapter{Zen miracle!!!}
The Zen master Bankei lived during the 17th` looks like below :
[image]

Here just below the chapter heading i.e. "Zen miracle!!!" i want to put some text say "-told by Master XYZ" possibly in italics (either left or right aligned) while keeping the gap between chapter title "Zen miracle" and the beginning text (The Zen master...) same. Can anyone please let me know how can it be done ? Thanks.

Based on the reply by @Bernard below, i tried with `\chapter[Zen miracle!!!]{Zen miracle!!!\\ told by Master XYZ}` and it shows up as :
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `\chapter[Zen miracle!!!]{Zen miracle!!!\\ told by Master XYZ}` do more or less what you want?

Comment: @Bernard : i tried and added the image above using what you told. Is it possible to reduce the size of "told by Master XYZ" and put it without bold fonts. Please let me know.

Comment: Yes. For the second line, use `\textit{\normalsize told by Master XYZ}`. If necessary,  add `\mdseries`. B.t.w., the style you should use  should be `hang` since the  chapter number and the chapter title  are on the same line.

Comment: @Bernard : Thanks a lot, what you told works. Also able to do it using ```\chapter[Zen miracle!!!]{Zen miracle!!!\\ \Large \normalfont - told by Master XYZ}``` . Can you please let me know what do you mean by the style ```hang``` and what will happen if i don't use it ?

Comment: With `hang`, the text added will start under the letter Z of the first line. As you can see, with `display, it starts under the chapter  number, which isn't very nice, from my point of view.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard , one more thing. Is there a easy way to keep it right aligned as well ? May be next reply you can put as answer to this question, though you have already provided the much needed info. Thanks a lot Bernard !!!

Comment: Do you mean, aligned at the rightmargin? Adding `\raggedleft ` just after \\ should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bernard, your answers really helped a lot !!!